# <small> not working in Swift attributed String

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, swift5

I have the following string coming from the backend.

```
Play million of songs ad-free across all your devices.* Terms and conditions applied.<br><br><small>* Requires a subscription</small>
```

I want the whole text to be in the custom font with 18 pt and the text under  to be small with the same custom font.

When I use the following code, it displays the entire string in 18 pt size, thus ignoring small tag.

```
func htmlAttributed(using font: UIFont, color: UIColor) -> NSMutableAttributedString? {
    do {
        let htmlCSSString = "<style>" +
            "html *" +
            "{" +
            "font-size: \(font.pointSize)pt !important;" +
            "color: #\(color.hexString) !important;" +
            "font-family: \(font.familyName), Helvetica !important;" +
        "}</style> \(self)"

        guard let data = htmlCSSString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) else {
            return nil
        }

        return try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data,
                                      options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                      documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Please help me in finding out the right way to display the small font text.

Comment: Isn't that because of the CSS, and not Swift? If you don't apply your html css, it should work. You are forcing the size of the text `"font-size: \(font.pointSize)pt !important;"`, your CSS modification seems to be causing the issue. I tried on my end, and got it work with the initial html string.

Comment: Just create a HTML test: In Terminal.app, `$>touch test.html`; put  the initial HTML code with a text editor, and open-ti with Safari.app. Replace the "initial HTML" code with your CSS modified one, you'll see. => Issue is HTML/CSS, not Swift. You'll find better answer tagging it correctly. No need for people to know Swift, but to know instead CSS/HTML